# How to access file in S3 bucket from lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a file a my S3 bucket and I want to access this file from a Lambda function.

When I pass the path of this file to one of the methods, I get the error:

> Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/https:/s3.amazonaws.com/TestBucket/testuser/AWS_sFTP_Key.pem".

For example:

```
TestMethod("https://s3.amazonaws.com/TestBucket/testuser/AWS_sFTP_Key.pem")
```

code:

```
public void FunctionHandler(S3Event s3Event, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
        {
            ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", "testuser",
                                                   new AuthenticationMethod[]{
            new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("testuser", new PrivateKeyFile[] {
                new PrivateKeyFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/TestBucket/testuser/AWS_sFTP_Key.pem")})
});

            SftpClient sftpClient = new SftpClient(connectionInfo);
            sftpClient.Connect();
            lambdaContext.Logger.Log(sftpClient.WorkingDirectory);
            sftpClient.Disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you are using.

Comment: Have you set up corresponding security policy and assigned it to the lambda?

Comment: @GiorgosDevYes, policies are in place.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein done that. Could you please advise?

Comment: I am very confused. If you want to access an object in Amazon S3, why does your function contain **sftp** code? Take a look at the code samples on [Step 2.1: Create a Deployment Package - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html) to see how to access S3 objects. (Not shown for C#, but you'll get the idea.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AWS SDK` for reading the file from S3 as shown below, however I would suggest to use `AWS Certificate Manager` or `IAM` for storing and managing your certificates and keys:

PS: Make sure you assign the proper role for your lambda function or bucket policy for your bucket to be able to `GetObject` from `S3`:

```cs
RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;//region where you store your file

client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);

GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();

request.WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME);//TestBucket
request.WithKey(S3_KEY);//testuser/AWS_sFTP_Key.pem

GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream);

String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

More Help:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, however I'm getting error as 'IAmazonS3' does not contain a definition for 'GetObject' and no extension method 'GetObject' accepting a first argument of type 'IAmazonS3' could be found .

Comment: You'll want to use GetObjectAsync, All S3 library methods are async now and named accordingly.